# how to get $oid from mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm try to export my collections from mongodb with mongoose and Nodejs , using `Modal.find();` to get all documents but it returns ids like `{_id:"5ee8b4b32af76531cd46d714"}` but I need to this type `{"_id":{"$oid":"5ee8b4b32af76531cd46d714"}`

can you help me to get this type of id from `Modal.find()` function?

> {"_id":{"$oid":"5ee8b4b32af76531cd46d714"}

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, You just want to modify output of `Model.find()`?
For that, you can use `aggregate` instead of `find`, and use `$addFields` in aggregation.

So, query should look like this

```js
model.aggregate([{$addFields: {_id: {"$oid": "$_id"}}}])
```

Problem with this query is that you can't actually use `$` as first char of some field name, because it is reserved character for mongo operations, for example `$addFields`

So, proper query will be withoud `$` in name of field

```js
model.aggregate([{$addFields: {_id: {oid: "$_id"}}}])
```

But I think it is not a good practice to override default `Document._id`, because it contains a bit more data than you expect.
For example, it contains timestamp when document was generated.

Comment: as said, if `$` is needed, then I am not sure can you execute it. There is `$literal` option for aggregate, but I am not sure it could be used for key of the field, so try to test with it.

I tested 2nd thing I wrote directly on db, and it is working 
I get an object like this `{   "_id" : {  "oid" : ObjectId("5881da602c9a170011275354") }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$literal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#treat-as-a-literal) to set `$oid`,

- `$literal` is a aggregation pipeline operator, you can use this in `find()` from MongoDB 4.4
- In expression, the dollar sign $ evaluates to a field path; i.e. provides access to the field.
- `$arrayToObject` convert k and v format array of object to object

```
Modal.find({},
{
  _id: {
    $arrayToObject: [
      [
        {
          k: { $literal: "$oid" },
          v: "$_id"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hTF1f_bAer0)

> You can use this in aggregate() method, using $addFields / $set / $project operators.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ALx6huApxxH)

Comment: no one will help when you just say *not working*, you need to share details what are you getting what is the problem are you facing. what is the version of your mongodb?